# What is more_body with HTTP response?

Tags: http, server-sent-events, web-frameworks, starlette, asgi

With the ASGI framework [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/), it has a streaming response that makes use of some `more_body` parameter in the HTTP response to denote if chunks have finished streaming ([source code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.33.0/starlette/responses.py#L244-L249)).  There is an article from Starlette talking about this: [Working with ASGI and HTTP](https://www.encode.io/articles/asgi-http).

Is this `more_body` technique a standard design pattern using HTTP, like [Server Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (SSE), or is it something specific to Starlette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `more_body` parameter used in Starlette's streaming response is not a standard HTTP feature, but a part of [ASGI (Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface) specifications](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/www.html). It is specific to asynchronous Python web frameworks like Starlette that use ASGI.

> `more_body (bool)` – Signifies if there is additional content to come (as part of a Request message).
>
> - If `True`, the consuming application should wait until it gets a chunk with this set to `False`.
> - If `False`, the request is complete and should be processed. Optional; if missing defaults to False.

In the context of ASGI and [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/), `more_body` is used to indicate whether the response is complete or if more data is expected. When a response is being streamed, setting `more_body` to `True` tells the ASGI server that more data chunks are forthcoming. Once the entire response has been sent, `more_body` should be set to `False`, signaling the end of the response.

That mechanism is different from standard HTTP features like [Server-Sent Events (SSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events). SSE is a standard that allows servers to push updates to clients over a single, long-lived HTTP connection. In contrast, the `more_body` approach is an ASGI-specific way to manage streaming responses within the framework's asynchronous processing model.

Answer (score 2):

Here I tried to prepare a comprehensive comparison as a table between SSE and the `more_body` flag plus websocket which is a close pattern to those techniques:

| Feature | HTTP Response Streaming (`more_body`) | WebSockets | Server-Sent Events (SSE) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Use Case** | Streaming large files or data | Real-time, bidirectional messaging | Real-time updates from server to client |
| **Direction** | Unidirectional (server → client) | Bidirectional (server ↔ client) | Unidirectional (server → client) |
| **Connection Type** | Single HTTP response | Persistent connection | Persistent connection |
| **Protocol** | HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 | ws:// or wss:// | HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 |
| **Data Flow** | Streamed in chunks | Independent messages | Event-driven messages |
| **Message Format** | Arbitrary data (binary or text) | Framed messages (binary or text) | Text-based event stream |
| **Browser Support** | Universal | Universal (with possible polyfills) | Universal (with possible polyfills) |
| **Persistent Connection** | No (but stream can be long-lived) | Yes | Yes |
| **Complexity** | Low | Medium | Low |
| **Overhead** | Low (standard HTTP) | Low (after handshake) | Low (standard HTTP) |

---

It is worth noting that there are some other technologies and approaches for communication on the web namely Long Polling, WebRTC, and GraphQL Subscriptions, to name a few.